# Adding and returning UTC time using PYTZ

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, utc, pytz

When I add an `order` to my `DB`, I would like to include the time as `UTC`.

```
ts = time.time()
utc = pytz.utc
orderDateUTC = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).replace(tzinfo=utc)

return add_order_to_db(tableID, userID, restaurantID, orderDateUTC, orderCost, orderStatus, orderItems)
```

When I add the `date` to the `DB`, I add it as `UTC` and then try and convert it back to `local time` just prior to returning it to the user.

**add_order_to_db(...)**

```
def add_order_to_db(tableID, userID, restaurantID, orderDateUTC, orderCost, orderStatus, orderItems):

    receivedOrder = ORDER(tableID, userID, restaurantID, orderDateUTC, orderCost, orderStatus)
    with contextlib.closing(DBSession()) as session:
        try:
           session.add(receivedOrder)
           session.commit()
        except exc.SQLAlchemyError, error:
            session.rollback()
            raise_database_error(error)
        else:
            au_tz = timezone('Australia/Sydney')
            au_dt = au_tz.normalize(orderDateUTC.astimezone(au_tz))
            receivedOrder.ORDERSDATE = au_dt
            order = Order(receivedOrder, 'true')
            return jsonify(data=order.serialize())
```

**serialize()**

```
   def serialize(self):                   
            return {                    
                'orderDate' : self.ORDERSDATE                                                                                                                                 
                }
```

`ORDERSDATE` is defined as:

```
ORDERSDATE = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
```

The issue is that the `time` is not being converted back properly.

The `returned output` and the data in the `DB` is: `orderDate: "Mon, 06 Apr 2015 01:13:00 GMT"`

However I need the `returned output` to be `orderDate: "Mon, 06 Apr 2015 11:13:00 GMT"`

I find that if I return `return str(au_dt)`, I get the correct output but in a different form: `2015-04-06 11:13:37.461000+10:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I need the returned output to be orderDate: "Mon, 06 Apr 2015 11:13:00 GMT"

It is incorrect. You don't need it if the following is true:

both

> The returned output and the data in the DB is: orderDate: "Mon, 06 Apr 2015 01:13:00 GMT"

and

> I find that if I return return str(au_dt), I get the **correct** output but in a different form: 2015-04-06 11:13:37.461000+10:00

are the *same* time:

```
local time = utc time + utc offset
     11:13 =    01:13 + 10
```